# Python: Return a list of dictionaries from a dictionary input with a new key

Tags: python

Is there a way to convert a dictionary into a list of dictionaries? The `data` has multiple key-value not only `s` and `r` but it could be `x`,`y`,and`z`.  The result should be in respective to their position so `si` should be with `ri`, and so on...

```
def binder(**kwargs):
    # do something to return a list of dictionaries


data = {
    's': ['si', 'so'],
    'r': ['ri', 'ro']
}

binder(data)
# result: [{'s': 'si', 'r': 'ri'}, {'s': 'so', 'r': 'ro'}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `list comprehension` in order to achieve your requirement.

```
data = {
    's': ['si', 'so'],
    'r': ['ri', 'ro']
}

keys = data.keys()
values = data.values()
list = [{key : values[i] for i, key in enumerate(keys) } for values in zip(*values)]
```

Output

```
[{'s': 'si', 'r': 'ri'}, {'s': 'so', 'r': 'ro'}]
```

**References**

- [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)
- [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)

I also provided below another approach without using `list comprehension`.

```
list = []
length = len(data['s'])
for i in range(length):
  dict = {}
  for key, value in data.items():
    dict[key] = value[i]
  list.append(dict)

print(list)
```

Output

```
[{'s': 'si', 'r': 'ri'}, {'s': 'so', 'r': 'ro'}]
```